# To fragment or not to fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

As I've started to adopt Fragments more and better but also as Fragments functionality is increased (Fragments in Fragments, MapFragments) I'm starting to reach a point where I need to define when I should make a new View/Action as a Fragment or as an Activity?

An Activity is defined as:

> An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do.

But a Fragments have kinda taken that definition instead as described in the docs:

> For example, a news application can use one fragment to show a list of
>   articles on the left and another fragment to display an article on the
>   right—both fragments appear in one activity

This is two things the user can do in one Activity with two Fragments.

So I'd like some input/help to figure out what is the best approach to decide if I should make a new action/view as a Fragment or as an Activity?

Comment: Mind explaining what the new views are? it really depends on what you are going to be doing with this new view/action

Comment: Like going from a list to detail etc.

Comment: But lets say we have a tab activity with lists in each tab and actionbar items which also has content to show.

Comment: Fragments generally are good for when you are tying together multiple types of views/functionality. In your case it sounds like you'd want to have a fragment for your list and a fragment for your details. This gives you the flexibility of reusing your fragment where you want to, placing the fragment where you need, replacing your fragments on the fly.. etc etc.. Plenty of advantages to fragments

Comment: @dymmeh I agree, which is why I've adopted it heavily. But I just had a project with a main activity on MANY lines of code doing nothing else than communicating between fragments starting/replacing fragments etc. so is this just the way to go or am I missing something?

Comment: I know the feeling of doing that. Unfortunately, to enable communication between fragments that's the way to do it. How many fragments do you generally have on screen? What are you passing between them?

Comment: @dymmeh Often I only have 1 fragment and usually I'm just passing some information which should be used to open a new fragment etc.

Comment: 1 fragment should be fairly trivial to handle I'd think? Maybe you can show us what you're doing and we can help slim it down

Comment: @dymmeh I'm not looking for a case based answer :) I'm looking for an idea/approach to how I should tackle it. I might already be using the best way but if someone out there had a good idea I'd like to hear it out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer depends on you and your development practices (or those of your company).  However, my opinion is this: At a minimum, if you think the functionality being developed could be used within multiple Activities, or if it could ever be used in an Activity alongside another view (as on a tablet), then you should make it a Fragment.

We've recently adopted the philosophy of creating Fragments in all cases.  Our Activities are now just top level coordinators, basically the glue that brings things together.  This makes for a consistent and flexible architecture.  This is important to us as we have numerous engineers at a couple of locations working on code.

Comment: Creating Fragments in all cases have also been my philosophy but sometimes you just have these huge cases which makes you wonder if this is good object oriented practice...

Comment: Yes, we have those too.  However, when I need to edit another developers code, I know the pattern and it makes it easy to analyze the code.  The ROI of using this pattern works for us.  You have to ask it if it works for you.

Comment: There are other options to keep Activities lighter and avoir to give them two roles like 1) be a fragment containter and 2) a coordinator of the ui logic of fragments. This will lead to a lack of cohesion and coupling will make it harder to reuse fragments. You could consider using an Event Bus for coordinating fragments like EventBus or Otto.

Answer (score 6):

> An Activity is defined as: "An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do"

That is more an issue of dated documentation than anything else. `Activity` has that same definition... when we are on a smaller screen size (e.g., phone). As you move up to larger screens, the odds of an activity being more complex than "a single, focused thing" increases.

> So I'd like some input/help to figure out what is the best approach to decide if I should make a new action/view as a Fragment or as an Activity?

Here is my general heuristic:

- If you anticipate that such-and-so piece of UI might exist standalone on a phone-sized screen, but be used in tandem with something else on a tablet-sized screen, make it a fragment.
- If you anticipate that such-and-so piece of UI will always exist standalone, just create a simple activity.
- If you anticipate that your ability to anticipate is not that good, err on the side of making more fragments. For example, you might say, "well, help will never need to be alongside anything else" and make it be an activity. Then, if you realize that *other pieces of UI* might benefit from the help being side-by-side with them rather than off on its own -- so the user can read the docs and perform the actions at the same time -- you will regret not having made help be a fragment, as you will have to do some re-work.
- If such-and-so piece of UI would never exist standalone -- in other words, if it is more like a single widget than a full activity -- and you anticipate using it on multiple projects, make it *be* a single widget, in the form of a custom `View` or `ViewGroup`.

But, as jsmith indicates, there is no universal right or wrong answer. BTW, AFAIAC, jsmith's answer is the correct one here, but I was going to be way too wordy for a comment on his answer... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've been developing in Android since 1.5 so I have been developing from quite some time Activities and recently Fragments.

Quite frequently fragments left me with a sour taste in my mouth... an example was when I needed a kind of paginated Dashboard with buttons. For that I used a ViewPager + 1 fragment per button. I had all kind of problems because before Android 4.2 fragments couldn't be nested.

Another problem was the asynchronous mode of function of the fragments that when the needed to be moved from one place to the other quite rapidly it had all kind of misbehaviours.

Don't think that all was bad... in more simple cases, the use of fragments worked quite nicely.

So, in my opinion, whenever you have an area that is self-contained, that isn't moved frequently on the views, that can be reused in several screens and also you support tablets (or my in the future), use it.

If you need nested fragments, views that are re-arranged quite frequently, or code that will not be reused, don't.